# Real estate photos with bright windows

Tags: photoshop

I am a real estate agent and have a canon 400 D with a wide angle lens EFS 10-18mm and a tripod. I know nothing about photography and the homes I photograph have all beautiful window views being a coastal town.Please help me with taking the photos as well as editing in photoshop CS 5 extended. I have no plugin programs and no external light source as well as no money to spend on expensive gear (need to sell a few houses first)
I need to have camera settings for normal lighting as well. I have been through lots of tutorials but cannot get anything right.

Comment: Hi Rudolf-en-lorrainne-henning, Welcome to photo.stackexchange. Could you edit-in an example of the effect you wish to duplicate so that we might diagnose the technique used to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look up HDR photography.  This is the easiest editing technique to compensate for scenes with huge contrast (very bright vs very dark).

Comment: You might find the built in HDR photo mode on your smartphone will get you the results you need for your work quickly, but don't lose heart, you'll find a tutorial that makes sense to you eventually and then get full value from your DSLR

Answer (score 1):

The windows are only bright some part of the day, sun goes naturally up and back down during the day unless very near the poles. This means that you get better results when the sun is less intense since all cameras have a limited dynamic-range, which is how much contrast they can capture in a frame.

Most real-estate images that show outdoor views are made using HDR technique but you can get very similar results using *Exposure Fusion*. All you need to do is take a bracket of images using your the AEB (Auto Exposure Bracketing) feature on your camera. It will take several images with different exposures, usually 3 is enough, even though some cameras can take up to 9. Then you load those images together in an Exposure Fusion program which will give you back an image with all parts of the image properly exposed. The HDR process is similar except that you get an HDR (High Dynamic-Range) image that must then be mapped back into an LDR (Low Dynamic-Range) image to be rendered or shown on-screen.